# Configuring client authentication glassfish 4

Tags: java, authentication, glassfish, certificate

i'm not used to GlassFish 4 and i'm trying to set up client authentication with certificate.

I've done some research and i've already created my certificate with key tool, added it to my session key store and in the cacerts.jks of my domain.

Then i've put the following in web.xml of my project :

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>certificate</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

And this in glassfish-web.xml :

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>authenticated</role-name>
    <group-name>app</group-name>
    <principal-name>CN=Test, OU=Dev, O=NAN, L=Test, ST=Test, C=FR</principal-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

Then nothing, when i try to visit my app using https or not my browser return an error "server unexpectedly closed the connection etc..."

I'm a bit stuck, i think i have missed some step but can't figure what.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you checked the server/access logs?

Comment: I have opened an exact same questions, did you eventually solve the issue ?